# Showing reSturctured text (.rst) structure overview in Sublime Text

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

Sublime Text 2 only has an additional **side bar** window, but it's inconvenient with bigger file, such as reStructuredText file with lots of contents.
So is there a plugin to show file structure in Sublime Text (haven't Google out so far), or it is possible to create a plugin to show the file structure?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such plugin as far as I know.

For your code files you can see the structure in Go to Symbol menu  (CMD+R on OSX)
if the files are supported by Sublime Text. SublimeCodeIntel provides "code intel" support for many programming languages.

[image: Example screenshot]

Sublime Text did not have a decent .RST structure parser last time I checked few months ago, but I would be really grateful if someone creates such plugin (willing to donate).

You can create syntax colorizer with the base Sublime Text (no Python coding needed), but for language analysis a full fetched plugin is required. I suggest you open another question for how to write such plugins.

Comment: Thanks! Recently I use `Restructured Text (RST) Snippets` plugin to write .rst create in Sublime Text 2, and just have read the basic plugin doc in Sublime Text site. Cause Sublime Text only has three windows(I think): Editer, Side bar and Minimap. So I don't have any idea to add a new window to show the structure.

Comment: SublimeText plugins do not support extra UI elements. You can exploit Go To Symbol window as in the example in the answer.